# DMCA deleted question still reviewable and displays original content

Tags: support, bug, status-review, review-queues, dmca-notice

I was reviewing in the First Questions queue and I was given the question [Java String Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77919111/java-string-questions) to review, which can't be viewed now. Whatever the reasons that made this question be deleted due to a DMCA takedown, after my review Stack Overflow indicates to me that this post is removed:

> This post was removed due to a DMCA takedown and is not accepting new reviews.

When reviewing the post [**all** the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOzKt.png) from the post, prior to the DMCA, is displayed.

I reviewed this question yesterday and today, which is after the takedown and I do not understand why as it requires new reviews.

Note that this question is not marked as audit.

Why do I keep having to review this question?

Comment: Oddly, that post doesn't even show up in your [review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11239251/skunka?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1)s; though that might also be intentional *because* of the DMCA,

Comment: Does the review show you the content of the post pre-DMCA? If so, I would suggest this is most certainly [[meta-tag:bug]] as even displaying the content in the review is likely against the DMCA (though it appears to be one anyway, users shouldn't expected to detect content that was/is subject to DMCA requests).

Comment: When did you get this review? According to the timeline the post was taken down at "2024-02-20 17:10:54Z" so if you had the review open from before that it might make sense. Otherwise there might have been some caching delay in removing the review after removing the question. If you are still getting this review I think you should add the [meta-tag:bug] tag to this question.

Comment: HUh, I just opened the First Questions review and got the question in question, [with ***all*** the content on display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOzKt.png) (intentionally redacted). This is most certainly a bug. If the OP doesn't edit this to improve what the problem is, I'll take the time to shortly.

Comment: Related: [Posts deleted as result of a DMCA Takedown Request still visible via suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391773/posts-deleted-as-result-of-a-dmca-takedown-request-still-visible-via-suggested-e) (Weirdly the answer from a staff member says its fixed even though that review item still shows the question)

Comment: I have edited the question to add infos and bug tag as I reviewed this question with all the content displayed after the takedown but feel free to edit to improve it

Comment: I also get this, and I can confirm I see all content before and after submitting a review. Also, clicking "Skip" does not prevent it from coming back later in the day, or the next day.

Comment: After sending a review (also clicking Skip) there are no buttons to move forward. A minor daily nuisance. While awaiting this bug to be fixed, I made a [userscript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428223/575796) to automatically skip this Question.

Comment: This is still happening today.

Comment: The same question is still in review today...

Comment: Just had the same question again