# How to block a Question from showing up in my First Question review queue

Tags: support, review-queues

There is a bug causing some questions to keep popping up day after day. As mentioned [over here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428213/dmca-deleted-question-still-reviewable-and-displays-original-content)

I have one such now (id [35682256](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35682256)). It is 3-weeks old and keeps bugging me daily.

Are there any means to block this question to keep it from annoying me further?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DMCA deleted question still reviewable and displays original content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428213/dmca-deleted-question-still-reviewable-and-displays-original-content)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat They are related, and they overlap. I guess we could say I'm looking more for an answer on how to block it from showing up for me, and the other question is why it keeps showing up.

Comment: "*I'm looking more for an answer on how to block it from showing up for me,*" you've tagged this as [[tag:bug]] thus you're reporting a bug. However, there likely isn't a way to block it for you. Considering it's a bug and all. You already *shouldn't be seeing them*. There is no site option for "disable this bug just for my account".

Comment: @VLAZ I have updated the question to remove all overlap with the other bug report, as well as removed the bug label.

Comment: Well if it were a normal review task you could have clicked on "Skip" and it would not be shown to you again. In this case even the skip button is not available. I guess you could try to fake that request somehow but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: OK, then the answer is "wait for the bug to be fixed". I don't know what else do you expect here. I am being as honest as possible: there isn't a way to fix the bug just for yourself. Unless you whip up a userscript or something but given that you haven't, I don't think you would after I told you this.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I click "Skip" on it every day. Clicking Skip _does not_ prevent it from showing up again.

Comment: @mikabytes weird I can't see the skip button, which probably means I can't see that because you've already reviewed it. Maybe that means that for some reason a new task keeps being generated somehow for that same question?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Indeed it is weird. It would make more sense if it was a new question with the same content being added every day. But this is asked on 1 Feb and keeps popping up.

Answer (score 6):

> Are there any means to block this question to keep it from annoying me further?

No, a bug means that the system does not work as intended or as wanted. So, the only real option is to wait for a fix for the bug.

An alternative might be to write a userscript that tries to work around the bug. Anybody is welcome to try.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the definitive answer. I will wrap up a userscript and post it here.

Answer (score 3):

As there are no built-in controls over filtering the review queue, here's a userscript for skipping questions based on title or Question ID. It has been tested using Violentmonkey.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        stackoverflow.com skip review
// @match       https://*.stackoverflow.com/review/*/*
// @version     1.0
// @author      mikabytes
// ==/UserScript==

const titleToSkip = `Java string questions` // change this to match other title
const idToSkip = `77919111` // change this to match other question id

async function run() {
  const title = getTitle()
  const id = getId()

  if (title === titleToSkip || id === idToSkip) {
    // there's no way to move forward after clicking 'skip' and receiving the DMCA notice,
    // so we have to reload to the queue main page

    // Convert:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35682256
    // ... into https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions
    const queueUrl = document.location.href.split(`/`).slice(0, -1).join(`/`)

    // go to page
    document.location = queueUrl
  }
}

function getTitle() {
  const el = document.querySelector(`.s-post-summary--content-title`)
  return el.textContent.trim()
}

function getId() {
  const el = document.querySelector(`.s-post-summary--content-title a`)
  const id = el.pathname.split(`/`)[2]
  return id
}

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  // wait for content to load
  while(!document.querySelector(`.s-post-summary--content-title`)) {
    await new Promise((res => setTimeout(res, 50)))
  }

  run()
})
```

Comment: You can probably match against the question ID which you can get from the link, which would be more reliable than a title based match.

Comment: Please could you explain how to use this userscript? And possibly generalise it to include any review task involving a DCMA takedown?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I did consider filtering by ID, but as this question has arisen before with different ID, I thought it best to make it more general. That being said, I have now updated it with an option to filter by either ID or title, as well as adapted it to work on any queue (not only First Questions).

Comment: @user10186832 There are many ways to install a userscript. First you need to install a userscript manager, see [How do I install a userscript](https://superuser.com/questions/252046/how-do-i-install-a-userscript), and then you copy/paste the code above into a new script. This will look a little different depending on what manager you use. For ViolentMonkey (which I use), you click the little monkey icon in the address bar, click the plus sign, paste the code and click "Save & Close"

Comment: @user10186832 I tried to make it general enough to match any review requests that encounter this DMCA bug. However, it doesn't seem to be possible. The only way to identify it is to send a review or click the "Skip" button, but we don't want to do that automatically for obvious reasons :-)

Comment: @mikabytes I think you mistake what I meant, I don't mean filtering by the review's ID but the question's ID instead. That `.question-hyperlink` element you were selecting was actually a link to the Question for which the review task was about. So you could get the question's ID to compare from there.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ah, gotcha. For some reason, I assumed the IDs were the same. I've updated the script to match on Question ID now.

Comment: @mikabytes thanks I will try it. :)

Comment: @mikabytes the DCMA review task just showed up again.  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35682256